# I want span class text by using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try

```
for html in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sg-row'}):
      name = html.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-medium a-colour-base a-text-normal'})
      print(name)`
```

Output: i got text with whole html attributesVivo Y91i (Ocean Blue,
2Storage) 
required O/P i need only text :Vivo Y91i (Ocean Blue,
2GB RAM, 32GB Storage)

Comment: What was the exact output that u got?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text` in order to print the text within the tag:

```
for html in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sg-row'}):
      name = html.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-medium a-colour-base a-text-normal'})
      print(name.text)
```

Comment: when i used it ,i got AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

```
` import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  for html in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'sg-row'}):
  name = html.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-medium a-colour-base a-text- 
   normal'})
  cleanr = re.compile('<.*?>')
  product_name = re.sub(cleanr,str(name))
  print(product_name)`
```

Comment: Pls post the full code. This much is not enough. Paste everything from the import statements to the last line of ur code.